# Choice parameter or Choice Variable in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

Currently, I am planning to build an application with all the environments in different plans. But when I see Bamboo it has lot of plans and its kind of confusion. Is there a way to implement all the environments within one plan and before running the plan it should show a drop down  to which environment should run and that will be executed. I have seen this option in Jenkins, I hope there will be plugin added to the Bamboo in implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are doing, but it sounds like you are trying to create a Plan that can deploy your application, and you have multiple environments you want to deploy to.

Bamboo gives you several ways to do this, but none of them are quite perfect in my opinion.  If I'm right about what you are doing, here are your options that I know of:

- Create multiple Plans as you are doing.  You can eliminate some of the busy work by creating your first plan (say "Deploy to DEV") and [cloning it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO053/Cloning+an+existing+plan) rather than manually re-typing everything for TEST.
- Create a single plan that is designed to use a variable for the environment, and run it manually as a [customized build](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/running-a-plan-build-manually-289276898.html) to provide a variable value that designates the environment name.
- Create a [Deployment Project and Environments](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/deployment-projects-338363438.html) instead of a Plan.  This ends up being similar to the first option, you do have to clone the tasks that do the deployment to each environment, but it brings some added advantages of Bamboo being explicitly aware of each environment, which release of your software is currently in each environment, and what the changes are that are inside that release.  Basically this treats environments and releases as first-class citizens in Bamboo that aren't things that exist or happen just behind the scenes of a regular build Plan.

It sounds like the middle option may be closest to what Jenkins allows.

The perfect solution in my mind would allow you to only have a single copy of the parts of tasks to do a deployment that are common to all environments, and a Deployment Project Environment just substitutes in those variables to that singe build execution that are specific to the Environment.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Currently we are using the 1st process, where we set the complete plan and its variables for DEV and clone for the rest Environments. Which brings up all 4-5 plans depends on the Environments. But now I am not sure if there is plan like Jenkins and Udeploy has a way to do the 'Choice Parameter or Choice Variable' as a plugin. All the Environments will be in the same one plan and wherever (say "Deploy to DEV') you hit the same plan, but before that you can choose an option to which Environment you want to deploy. So, same like is there an option in Bamboo to execute it.

Comment: That sounds exactly like option 2 above in bamboo.  If you trigger the plan manually, you can select "customized build", and supply value to one or more variables.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd option is what I am thinking to implement, every time I trigger the to run build, then I need to disable the other stages and run it. It will be harder to remember ever time